# Barrier options in LSV (local stochastic volatility) / Austing's Smile pricing explained

Tags: stochastic-volatility, local-volatility, barrier

In his book (chapters 9.5 to 9.7), Peter Austing argues that barrier options are insensitive to the details of the stochastic volatility model used in a LSV model, except for the level of vol of vol. In particular, he claims that there is no point in including a spot-volatility correlation in the stochastic volatility part of the LSV model because the effect is already taken into account in the local volatility part of the LSV model.

Through testing, I find that correlation has on the contrary a large impact on the price of DIPs (down and in puts) and UOCs (up and out calls), and of course on DOPs and UICs through the In-Out parity. I even find that the vol of vol sensitivity actually changes sign for some value of correlation. For example a DIP price goes up with increasing vol of vol when correlation is close to -1. However it goes down with with increasing vol of vol when correlation is higher (already for negative values of correlation). Conversely, the UOC price goes up with increasing vol of vol except when correlation is close to +1.
The DIP case is particularly interesting because it's the most popular barrier option type on equity derivatives (by far) and the required correlation for calibrating a SV model to an equity vol surface is usually close to -1.

My LSV implementation is in Monte Carlo with the particles method by Guyon and Henry-Labordere. The SV model is either lambda-SABR as suggested by Austing or the one in "Calibrating and pricing with embedded local volatility models" (Ren Madan Qian 2007), it does not make a difference. Vanillas of all strikes and maturities are repriced very accurately for every (correlation, vol of vol) pair tested (MAE ~ 0.2bp, worst fit ~ 1bp).

Does anyone have the same experience?